# perl: how to use my own objects?

Tags: perl

I have a module in a directory: cs351/linked_list/LinkedList:

```
package cs351::linked_list::MyLinkedList;

sub mynew { ...
```

the test file is in cs351:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use lib 'cs351';
use linked_list::MyLinkedList;

my $test = MyLinkedList->mynew();
```

output:

```
perl test_linked_list.pl | grep 'nothing'
Can't locate object method "mynew" via package "MyLinkedList" (perhaps you forgot to load "MyLinkedList"?) at test_linked_list.pl line 6.
```

I just tried to make something from a perl beginner book. I checked perlootut but it doesn't  specifically mention

please don't ask about the linked list thing. at all. Its not relevant to the question.

Comment: shouldn't it be "use cs351::linked_list::MyLinkedList;"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't being consistent about what you call this package.

In the code snippets you've provided, you're referring to your class using three different package names:

- `cs351::linked_list::MyLinkedList` (in the `package` declaration)
- `linked_list::MyLinkedList` (in the `use` statement)
- `MyLinkedList->mynew` (when trying to invoke a function on it)

This isn't correct. Package names are identifiers, not paths; they don't change based on where you are.

Assuming that your package is in a file named `cs351/linked_list/LinkedList.pm`, the correct way to refer to it would be as `linked_list::LinkedList` (note*):

- `package linked_list::LinkedList;`
- `use linked_list::LinkedList;`
- `linked_list::LinkedList->mynew`

---

*: Note that this isn't generally considered an acceptable class name. Class names are usually in title case, and don't generally contain underscores.